# Nginx Server Block Ordering

Tags: ssl, nginx

I have multiple sites on a subdomain that I am trying to serve using nginx, some of the subdomains are being served with SSL and some are not. I'm having some trouble getting the non-SSL sites to serve properly. Whenever I try to access them, they immediately redirect (with the correct host) to the SSL/HTTPS version. I've attached my location block below. I've read the nginx block on request processing but can't figure out how to force the unencrypted hosts not to get forwarded. (http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/request_processing.html)

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name dev.example.ca dev.example.server2.example.tl;

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/home/example/example/socket.sock;
    }
    location /static {
        autoindex on;
        alias /home/litobro/example/example/static/;
    }
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name dutyroster.example.ca;

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/home/example2/dutyroster/socket.sock;
    }
    location /static {
        autoindex on;
        alias /home/example/example2/static/;
    }

    location /socket.io {
        proxy_pass http://unix:/home/example/example2/socket.sock;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_buffering off;

        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
    }
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name ex3.server2.example.tl example.ca www.example.ca;

    location ~ .well-known/acme-challenge/ {
        root /var/www/letsencrypt;
        default_type text/plain;
    }

    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    server_name example.ca www.example.ca example.server2.example.tl;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.ca/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.ca/privkey.pem;
    include snippets/ssl-params.conf;

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/home/example/example3/socket.sock;
    }
}
```

I ordered the server blocks such that the port 80 requests would hopefully get hit first but this still seems to not be working. Thanks in advance for the help! (The server blocks are mostly stripped of the actual domains, though I think I got consistency on the domain replacements)

Comment: That did it! I had includeSubdomains on in my ssl-params. Thanks a bunch! Could you submit that as an answer so I could mark this solved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cause of the problem is the [HSTS](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6797) header, which is set inside `snippets/ssl-params.conf`. This header tells the browser that the website will connect only over HTTPS. Here is an example of how this header is set with Nginx:

```
add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubdomains;";
```

If the header value contains `includeSubDomains` flag, like in the example above, then the HSTS policy will also apply to all subdomains of the main domain. And that was the reason why your browser tried to send all requests to the subdomain over HTTPS.

Keep in mind that modern browsers store the list of HSTS websites in a special cache, so simply removing or modifying the header in Nginx may not cause any immediate effect. You will need to clear the HSTS cache manually in a manner specific to your browser.

It is also worth mentioning that using the `includeSubDomains` flag is considered to be a [good practice](https://shrikantadhikarla.wordpress.com/2013/02/18/anatomy-of-includesubdomains-directive-in-http-strict-transport-security-policy/), so keeping it and issuing a certificate for your subdomains instead might be a good idea. Currently there are several certificate authorities, like [Let's Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org), that provide free of charge and easy to install certificates.

Answer (score 0):

sorry, i don't have many experience with nginx, but you have two server blocks in the end of your conf file. The first listening to port 80 you have "return 301 https://$host$request_uri;" is this line needed?

try commenting that line and see if your non-ssl server names still redirect to https.

Comment: I'm using that to force some hosts to force ssl, when I take that line out, those hosts are no longer forced, but then the other hosts also work without ssl. It's taking priority over the other hosts for some reason and I'm not sure why.